# How does the Inset Boundary option work?

Tags: modeling

Insetting the two faces shown on this mesh (which has a mirror modifier) and pressing <kbd>B</kbd> seems to work as intended, toggling whether the middle edge is inset or not.
[image: 1]

However, when insetting the face shown here, toggling the *Boundary* option does nothing.
[image: 2]

Why is this?

Comment: please explain what is not working as expected..

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation about your issue, don't just post, images, videos or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I believe Nour is just confused about the functionality of the _Boundary_ option of the _Inset_ tool. I have an answer in the works and I can submit an edit to the question to fix things up a bit if necessary.

Comment: @HISEROD Thanks for taking the time to investigate As it stands the value of this question is very limited because it makes a poor job of explaining the issue, as such people facing similar problems will have a hard time finding this in the future. Answers here may go to waste by finding little audience. We should encourage users to make an effort and post high quality questions by edit their posts themselves. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: If you can edit the question into shape please do so,a flag for reopening will be submitted automatically, however we should encourage users to make improvements themselves

Comment: @HISEROD Thanks for taking the effort of taking screenshots of the video I posted.
I'm more like a visual guy and explaining with words is not my best skill. 
For some reason, I couldn't upload the video to be hosted in the question itself. I think it was big. I'm sure saying a video in the same page would have made a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary option on an inset faces operation will only inset new faces where the mesh doesn't have a boundary (where the edges connect 2 or more faces).  Where face edges have only a single edge, no new edges will be created:

[image]

Any difference in behavior from toggling "boundary" on the operation depends on whether the edges of the inset face are manifold-- which is not apparent in either of your flat shaded example images.

Comment: That clears things up, thanks a lot.
I think I will be asking another question on how to get the same effect if the face I'm inset-ing is not on the edge. I don't like merging the vertices of the extra face.